How use Accordion Component from Gluestackv2 in React Native App?
I used the <Accordion /> example from Gluestack v2, but the text in  is not displayed when pressing the plus/minus arrows. I can't figure out how it works.
Here is an accordion with three elements, each of which should be opened separately by pressing the plus and closed for a minute. They are named item-1,item-2, item-3, but each part  in element doen't work.
export const AddInfo = () => {
    const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = React.useState(['item-1', 'item-2', 'item-3']);
    return (
        <Accordion
            variant="unfilled"
            type="multiple"
            value={selectedValues}
            onValueChange={(item) => setSelectedValues(item)}
            className="m-5 w-[95%]"
        >
            <AccordionItem
                value="item-1"
                className="border-t border-b border-outline-300"
            >
                <AccordionHeader>
                    <AccordionTrigger>
                        {({ isExpanded }) => {
                            return (
                                <>
                                    <AccordionTitleText>
                                        Exploring Nature's Wonders
                                    </AccordionTitleText>
                                    {isExpanded ? (
                                        <AccordionIcon as={MinusIcon} />
                                    ) : (
                                        <AccordionIcon as={PlusIcon} />
                                    )}
                                </>
                            );
                        }}
                    </AccordionTrigger>
                </AccordionHeader>
                <AccordionContent>
                    <AccordionContentText>
                        Embark on a journey through the breathtaking landscapes and diverse
                        ecosystems of our planet. From majestic mountains to serene oceans, discover
                        the beauty that nature has to offer.
                    </AccordionContentText>
                </AccordionContent>
            </AccordionItem>

            <AccordionItem value="item-2">
                <AccordionHeader>
                    <AccordionTrigger>
                        {({ isExpanded }) => {
                            return (
                                <>
                                    <AccordionTitleText>
                                        The Art of Culinary Delights
                                    </AccordionTitleText>
                                    {isExpanded ? (
                                        <AccordionIcon as={MinusIcon} />
                                    ) : (
                                        <AccordionIcon as={PlusIcon} />
                                    )}
                                </>
                            );
                        }}
                    </AccordionTrigger>
                </AccordionHeader>
                <AccordionContent>
                    <AccordionContentText>
                        Indulge your senses in a culinary adventure. Uncover the secrets behind
                        delectable dishes, learn about unique flavor profiles, and ignite your
                        passion for cooking.
                    </AccordionContentText>
                </AccordionContent>
            </AccordionItem>
            <AccordionItem
                value="item-3"
                className="border-t border-b border-outline-300"
            >
                <AccordionHeader>
                    <AccordionTrigger>
                        {({ isExpanded }) => {
                            return (
                                <>
                                    <AccordionTitleText>
                                        Mastering the Creative Process
                                    </AccordionTitleText>
                                    {isExpanded ? (
                                        <AccordionIcon as={MinusIcon} />
                                    ) : (
                                        <AccordionIcon as={PlusIcon} />
                                    )}
                                </>
                            );
                        }}
                    </AccordionTrigger>
                </AccordionHeader>
                <AccordionContent>
                    <AccordionContentText>
                        Immerse yourself in the world of creativity. Unleash your artistic
                        potential, whether it's through writing, painting, or any other form of
                        expression.
                    </AccordionContentText>
                </AccordionContent>
            </AccordionItem>
        </Accordion>
    );
};

I dug through all the documentation, there is little information on the details of how the expansion works.

You are have assigned selectedValues a list and later inside onValueChange, you are updating it to a single value. I think list of values and selected values need to be separated. Also try not to pass the value prop to the Accordion instead pass your value in the AccordionItem component.

I tried to create a new empty react-native project, installed dependencies and all examples worked. This is some internal error of the project I am working on. I will try to figure it out. Thanks for your help.

The above code should work fine, but please ensure you have the proper imports for the Icons. For gluestack-ui v2, it is recommended to use the lucide-react-native icons

Thanks, I use lucide-react-native as recommended and it works.
import { MinusIcon } from "lucide-react-native";
import { PlusIcon } from "lucide-react-native";
The main problem is logic for uncollapse item. I can't see what in <AccordionContent><AccordionContentText> is.

Can you provide more details about the project or codebase you're working on? Feel free to report any issues or bugs on GitHub as well.
